# Need help rewriting a Haskell program that groups words by anagrams in OCaml (or any ML)?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pattern-matching, ocaml

I wrote a Haskell function that groups words by anagrams. I'm trying to learn OCaml, but I'm a little confused as to how use pattern matching in OCaml. Could someone help translate this to OCaml for me? Thank you!

This function takes a list of strings, and partitions it into a list of string lists, grouped by anagrams.

```hs
import Data.List

groupByAnagrams :: [String] -> [[String]]
groupByAnagrams []     = []
groupByAnagrams (x:xs) = let (listOfAnagrams, listOfNonAnagrams) = (partitionByAnagrams (sort x) xs)
                         in 
                         (x:listOfAnagrams):(groupByAnagrams listOfNonAnagrams)
```

This helper function takes a sorted string `sortedStr`, and a list of strings (the reason the string is sorted is so that I don't have to call sort on it every iteration). The string list is partitioned into two lists; one consisting of the strings that are anagrams to `sortedStr`, the other consisting of the strings that are not. The function returns the tuple that consists of these two lists.

```hs
partitionByAnagrams :: String -> [String] -> ([String], [String])
partitionByAnagrams sortedStr []     = ([], [])
partitionByAnagrams sortedStr (x:xs) 
         | (sortedStr == (sort x))   = let (listOfAnagrams, listOfNonAnagrams) = (partitionByAnagrams sortedStr xs)
                                       in
                                       (x:listOfAnagrams, listOfNonAnagrams)
         | otherwise                 = let (listOfAnagrams, listOfNonAnagrams) = (partitionByAnagrams sortedStr xs)
                                       in
                                       (listOfAnagrams, x:listOfNonAnagrams)
```

This is just a test case:

```hs
test1 = mapM_ print (groupByAnagrams ["opts", "alerting", "arrest", "bares", "drapes", "drawer", "emits", "least", "mate", "mates", "merit", "notes", "palest", "parses", "pores", "pots", "altering", "rarest", "baser", "parsed", "redraw", "items", "slate", "meat", "meats", "miter", "onset", "pastel", "passer", "poser", "spot", "integral", "raster", "bears", "rasped", "reward", "mites", "stale", "meta", "steam", "mitre", "steno", "petals", "spares", "prose", "stop", "relating", "raters", "braes", "spared", "warder", "smite", "steal", "tame", "tames", "remit", "stone", "plates", "sparse", "ropes", "tops", "triangle", "starer", "saber", "spread", "warred", "times", "tales", "team", "teams", "timer", "tones", "staple", "spears", "spore"])
```

**EDIT!!! This is a rewritten version of my function. Thanks to jrouquie for pointing out the inefficiency!
**EDITED AGAIN ON 10/7 - used pattern matching on tuples for clarity, no need for all those fsts and snds.

```
groupByAnagrams2 :: [String] -> [[String]]
groupByAnagrams2 str = groupBySnd $ map (\s -> (s, (sort s))) str

groupBySnd :: [(String, String)] -> [[String]]
groupBySnd []           = []
groupBySnd ((s1,s2):xs) = let (listOfAnagrams, listOfNonAnagramPairs) = (partitionBySnd s2 xs)
                          in
                          (s1:listOfAnagrams):(groupBySnd listOfNonAnagramPairs)


partitionBySnd :: String -> [(String, String)] -> ([String], [(String, String)])
partitionBySnd sortedStr []                = ([], [])
partitionBySnd sortedStr ((s, sSorted):ss)
              | (sortedStr == sSorted)     = let (listOfAnagrams, listOfNonAnagramPairs) = (partitionBySnd sortedStr ss)
                                             in
                                             (s:listOfAnagrams, listOfNonAnagramPairs)
              | otherwise                  = let (listOfAnagrams, listOfNonAnagramPairs) = (partitionBySnd sortedStr ss)
                                             in
                                             (listOfAnagrams, (s, sSorted):listOfNonAnagramPairs)
```

Comment: Note that while `sortedStr` is indeed sorted only once, each element of the remainig list `xs` is sorted once for each call to `partitionByAnagrams`. You might want to sort (a copy of) the whole list once and for all. (This uses more memory.)

Comment: @jrouquie How will that decrease the number of sortings? Either way all strings in the list will be sorted, right?

Comment: If you sort a sorted string it is at least a **O(n)** operation, because the algorithm still has to look at each element to see if the list is sorted. @jrouquie, how would that lead to more memory usage?

Comment: @jrouquie I think I know what you're saying - some of the remaining strings will be sorted more than once.

Comment: On the example input `["foo", "bar", "qux", "egg"]`, your code calls `partitionByAnagrams (sort x) xs` 4 times, with `xs` taking resp. values `["bar", "qux", "egg"]`, `["qux", "egg"]`, `["egg"]`, `[]`. Since `partitionByAnagrams x xs` sorts each element of `xs` once, `"egg"` is sorted 3 times. More precisely, this code calls `sort` Θ(n²) times, while it could call it only O(n) times. (edit : yes, you're right.)

Answer (score 6):

I have to say that I find your Haskell code a bit clumsy. That is, your original function could have been written much more concise; for example:

```
import Control.Arrow ((&&&))
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.List (groupBy, sortBy)

anagrams :: Ord a => [[a]] -> [[[a]]]
anagrams =
  map (map fst) .
  groupBy ((==) `on` snd) .
  sortBy (compare `on` snd) .
  map (id &&& sortBy compare)
```

That is:

- `map (id &&& sortBy compare)` pairs each string in the list with a sorted list of its characters;
- `sortBy (on compare snd)` sorts the list of pairs that you now have on their second components, i.e., the sorted list of characters;
- `groupBy (on (==) snd)` groups all consecutive items in the sorted list that have identical lists of sorted characters;
- finally, `map (map fst)` drops the lists of sorted characters and leaves you with just the original strings.

For example:

```
Prelude> :m + Control.Arrow Data.Function Data.List

Prelude Control.Arrow Data.Function Data.List> ["foo", "bar", "rab", "ofo"]
["foo","bar","rab","ofo"]

Prelude Control.Arrow Data.Function Data.List> map (id &&& sortBy compare) it
[("foo","foo"),("bar","abr"),("rab","abr"),("ofo","foo")]

Prelude Control.Arrow Data.Function Data.List> sortBy (compare `on` snd) it
[("bar","abr"),("rab","abr"),("foo","foo"),("ofo","foo")]

Prelude Control.Arrow Data.Function Data.List> groupBy ((==) `on` snd) it
[[("bar","abr"),("rab","abr")],[("foo","foo"),("ofo","foo")]]

Prelude Control.Arrow Data.Function Data.List> map (map fst) it
[["bar","rab"],["foo","ofo"]]
```

"Translating" to Caml will then leave you with something along the lines of

```
let chars xs =
  let n = String.length xs in
  let rec chars_aux i =
    if i = n then [] else String.get xs i :: chars_aux (i + 1)
  in
  List.sort compare (chars_aux 0)

let group eq xs =
  let rec group_aux = function
    | [] -> []
    | [x] -> [[x]]
    | x :: xs ->
        let ((y :: _) as ys) :: yss = group_aux xs in
        if eq x y then (x :: ys) :: yss else [x] :: ys :: yss
  in
  group_aux xs

let anagrams xs =
  let ys = List.map chars xs in
  let zs = List.sort (fun (_,y1) (_,y2) -> compare y1 y2) (List.combine xs ys) in
  let zs = group (fun (_,y1) (_,y2) -> y1 = y2) zs in
  List.map (List.map fst) zs
```

Here, the helper function `chars` takes a string to a sorted list of characters, while `group` should give you some insight in how to do pattern matching on lists in Caml.

Comment: Thanks for your insights! I'm not as familiar with all of Haskell's features as I'd like to be, though (esp. the &&& operator). Could you clarify the flow of the functions?

Comment: @dxh I've added a brief explanation of the Haskell version and a step-by-step example to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

The most general form of pattern matching is the `match` expression, which is the same as the `case` expression in Haskell.

```
let rec groupByAnagrams lst =
  match lst with [] -> ...
               | x::xs -> ...
```

However, when only the last argument of a function needs to be pattern-matched (as is the case here), there is a shortcut using the `function` syntax:

```
let rec groupByAnagrams = function
    [] -> ...
  | x::xs -> ...
```

As for the guards, there is no exact equivalent; you can use `when` inside a pattern match, but that only applies to a particular pattern, and you have to repeat that pattern for all the cases you want. You could also use `if ... then ... else if ... then ... else ...` but that is not as pretty.

```
let rec partitionByAnagrams sortedStr = function
    [] -> ...
    x::xs when ...(some condition here)... -> ...
    x::xs -> ...
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I'll try it with an if-then-else.